# Android running on UI thread even when using worker thread

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

I am using a worker thread, as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) but still the code is blocking the UI. If I sleep at the beginning of the run() method, it doesn't block the UI. The thing is, it's a heavy code that runs from the onCreate method, but no matter what I do, I can't make it not block the UI. What am I doing wrong?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                Log.d("asdf", "asdf");
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Can we see some of the code you're expressing has a problem?

Comment: what makes you think that it is blocking the UI thread as is?

Comment: @A--C, have you ever seen a thread in android? [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/05/painless-threading.html)

Comment: hey, you're right... it's something else! back to the drawing board... thanks for your time

Comment: @vault You're right, I have never seen a Thread in Android. Ty for the link!

Comment: Thread is taking a new Runnable because that is one of the ways you create an anonymous thread in Java. I think the reason you are seeing degraded performance is that your thread is very CPU/storage intensive. Try placing a sleep in there to slow the loop down and I would think the UI would become more responsive.

Comment: code seems to me correct..not sure why It is blocking UI in main thread. You should check other code too.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using an AsyncTask - which is the control Android uses to do long running processes off the UI thread.

Bottom line, use this and you will have much more success.

[AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Handler` to or `.runOnUiThread(runnable)` to call your UI thread.
You can execute your thread without the Runnable as well, like this:

```
new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                Log.d("asdf", "asdf");
            }
        }
    }).start();
```